# Run Keter without GHC and cabal

Tags: yesod, keter

I have a server and want to deploy my Yesod applications without installing GHC and Cabal. I am not sure if is possible: a Teacher told me that I must first compile Keter in my machine and, after that, put `keter` executable on the server, though I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build Keter, first you'll need to clone the sources from its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter). Then you'll need to set up a Haskell build environment and use `cabal build` or `cabal install` to build the sources. Personally, I use a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) container derived from an image based on the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM haskell:7.10.2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  git
RUN mkdir /src
RUN cd src && \
  git clone https://github.com/snoyberg/keter && \
  cd keter && \
  git checkout e8b5a3fd5e14dfca466f8acff2a02f0415fceeb0
WORKDIR /src/keter
RUN cabal update
RUN cabal install keter
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

This is an image containing the Keter sources checked out at a specific revision with the minimum GHC toolchain required to build it all. The `cabal` command lines pull down all the project's dependencies and compiles the whole thing. Once this has completed, you can grab the `keter` executable from `~/.cabal/bin/keter`.

Even if you choose not to use Docker, this file should give you a rough idea how to set up your environment.

Now you have Keter compiled, you can run it inside another Docker container. Here's a rough idea what the `Dockerfile` for the corresponding image might look like:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libgmp-dev \
  nano \
  postgresql
COPY keter /opt/keter/bin/
COPY keter-config.yaml /opt/keter/etc/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/opt/keter/bin/keter", "/opt/keter/etc/keter-config.yaml"]
```

Ths will take a base Debian image and install a minimal set of packages on top of it. It then copies the `keter` executable and configuration file into the image. If you then run a container from the resulting image it will start the `keter` executable.

Fair warning: This whole process is fairly involved. I'm still working on tweaking the exact details myself. Good luck!